# Adding metadata to learning material using mysql

Tags: mysql, metadata

am developing a mysql database that contains large collection of learning materials, and i need to know how to add metadata to each material using mysql
is there any authoring tool that can assist in creating the metadata

anyone can help regarding this matter

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for information about the tables and databases themselves, you may be looking for INFORMATION_SCHEMA http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

If you're attempting to add your own "metadata" about items in tables or databases, I would suggest creating a parallel table/database to store the information and do your own operations on it. Alternatively, change the layout of your tables to include fields for comments such that comments are in a definite position with respect to the data is concerns.